# C++ Webcam Capture in VS 2012 - Library Error: "Unable to Start Program"

Tags: webcam, capture

Trying to capture video from my webcam device using Visual Studio 2012 with C++.  My goal is to be able to view live feed from a USB camera for some ROV projects. I found a website (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559437/Capturing-video-from-web-camera-on-Windows-and) that has a Visual Studio solution.  However, when I compile, I get an error that reads: "Unable to start program.  VideoInputVS2012\videoInput\Debug\videoInput.lib".  I tried including the library in the solution, but it didn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What type of project are you building? If it is a static library you will not be able to run it. You may want to check your Project settings for the output target type.

---

-----------------------**Updated Edit**--------------------------------------------------

---

The codeproject code you downloaded has a project that generaters a static .lib file.
You will need to create a another project that references this .lib file in order to use  it.

There are actually two downloads that show the .lib class being used.

1. TestVideoInputVS2012x86.zip - uses the OpenCV framework for presenting live video
2. The second example is based on the SimpleCapture example from the
   Windows SDK (this code -SimpleCaptureVS2012x86.zip, application -
   SimpleCaptureVS2012x86-exe.zip).

Here is also an example provided of how to call the videoInput.lib static class:
For using this library it is enough to include videoInput.h and videoInput .lib in your project. This class is made as a singleton which makes managing of resources easy.

`//TestvideoInput.cpp`
`#include "stdafx.h"`
`#include "videoInput.h"`

```
#pragma comment(lib,"videoInput.lib")

...
```

The codeproject being referenced and discussed was created by [Evgeny Pereguda](http://www.codeproject.com/Members/Evgeny-Pereguda)

Comment: It is using a .lib file instead of a .dll, so would that mean it is static?

Comment: Yes it is a static .lib file. See upated answer to get the other code which will show you how to use it.